# React + chartjs app becomes slow as add charts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

Very new to reactjs. I have a reactjs app displaying some charts with react-chartjs-2. I provide the data for the charts through api call. If charts are up to three the app runs quickly. But, as I add charts the app getting slower. What gets slow is the drawing of the charts. My data comes quickly from the api but the charts first shows nothing and after several seconds showing up. In addition, I tried another react library for charts (nivojs) and behaves the same. The more the charts I add the more slower getting. So that makes me think that is a react issue(I mean bad implementation from my side) as I do not have any expirience with it.Below is the code for my dynamic component for rendering a chart with chartjs. I have disable the strict mode in react and nothing change from performance perspective. In order to display all these charts I use swiper as a slider but do not cause any performance issue, because if I render inside or outside of the swiper the performace stays the same.
[image: This is how they look, all charts, until drawing completes]

```
import { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from "react";
import "./BarChart.css";
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from "chart.js";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";
import { Dna } from "react-loader-spinner";

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
);

export const options = {
  responsive: true,
  animation: false,
};

function BarChart(props) {
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({});
  const [xAxis, setXAxis] = useState([]);
  const [yAxis, setYAxis] = useState([]);
  const [slideTitle, setSlideTitle] = useState("");
  const [htmlText, setHtmlText] = useState("");
  const [paragraphTitle, setParagraphTitle] = useState("");
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(
    function () {
      fetch(`this is a call to my api`)
        .then(function (response) {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (data) {
          setXAxis(data.data[props.slideData.xAxis]);
          setYAxis(data.data[props.slideData.yAxis]);
          setChartData({
            labels: xAxis,
            datasets: [
              {
                label: "Users Gained",
                data: yAxis,
                backgroundColor: ["red"],
                borderColor: "red",
              },
            ],
          });
          setSlideTitle(data.data.slide_title);
          setHtmlText(data.data.html_text);
          setParagraphTitle(data.data.paragraph_title);
          setLoaded(true);
        });
    },
    [loaded]
  );

  if (!loaded) {
    return (
      <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
        <Dna
          visible={true}
          height="20vh"
          width="20vw"
          ariaLabel="dna-loading"
          wrapperStyle={{}}
          wrapperClass="dna-wrapper"
        />
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className="slideTitle w-100">
          <h1 className="mt-5">{slideTitle}</h1>
          <div className="pseudoBorder"></div>
        </div>
        <div className=" d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          <div className="chart col-10">
            <Bar data={chartData} options={options} />
          </div>
          <div className="text-for-chart col-2 p-4">
            <p className="paragraphTitle text-danger ">{paragraphTitle}</p>
            <div
              className="htmlText"
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlText }}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default BarChart;
```

Comment: Code looks decent, possible throttling from api based on number of queries or amount of data?

Comment: Not totally sure of the error but as someone who has started using chartjs myself I have a few suggestions. Chartjs has an animation function that can be turned off and that can significantly improve performance if you are re-rendering charts at all. Also @Brent's point is a good one. You could be getting throttled. Most web browsers have a call limit. One way to get around this I made was to instead store my data onto files and then call them in chunks and just parse the data off the files. Lastly its possible async functions may help avoid any bottle necks.

Answer (score 0):

I changed how I manage both state and useEffect and now the drawing have no issue. As the documentation says, if multiple states change together combine them in a single object and that is what I did.
What I change:
As mentioned, I change the state into one object:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
    chartData: {
      labels: [],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Users Gained",
          data: [],
          backgroundColor: ["red"],
          borderColor: "red",
        },
      ],
    },
    slideData: {
      slideTitle: "",
      htmlText: "",
      paragraphTitle: "",
    },
  });
```

And I change the useEffect to only run the first time that the component mounts:

```
useEffect(function () {
    fetch(`this is a call to my api`)
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function (data) {
        setData({
          chartData: {
            labels: data.data[props.slideData.xAxis],
            datasets: [
              {
                label: "Users Gained",
                data: data.data[props.slideData.yAxis],
                backgroundColor: ["red"],
                borderColor: "red",
              },
            ],
          },
          slideData: {
            slideTitle: data.data.slide_title,
            htmlText: data.data.html_text,
            paragraphTitle: data.data.paragraph_title,
          },
        });
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);
```